# Parar o loop ou não

Tags: python, loop, condição

Bom dia,

Estou com dificuldade para colocar uma condição neste loop: se apertar 1 volta para laço caso  aperte 2  sai do laço

```
resp=1

while resp==1:
    cliente_nome.append((input("Digite o nome do Cliente: ")))
    cliente_cpf.append(input("Digite o Cpf: "))
    cliente_idade.append(input("digite a idade: "))
    cliente_depositar.append(input("Quanto desejar depositar: "))
    resp=input("deseja continuar 1-para sim  2-para não")
    if resp==2:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e depois o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O tipo de resp é **string** e tu testa se é igual a um **int**. Nunca vai funcionar assim.

Duas formas diferentes de resolver o problema:

---

### Primeira solução

Na linha 8, mudar a atribução de **resp** para **int**

```
resp=int(input("deseja continuar 1-para sim  2-para não"))
```

### Segunda solução

Mudar o tipo de **resp** para **string** em todas as suas referências:

```py
resp="1"

while resp=="1":
    cliente_nome.append((input("Digite o nome do Cliente: ")))
    cliente_cpf.append(input("Digite o Cpf: "))
    cliente_idade.append(input("digite a idade: "))
    cliente_depositar.append(input("Quanto desejar depositar: "))
    resp=input("deseja continuar 1-para sim  2-para não")
    if resp=="2":
        break
    else:
        continue
```

---

Neste caso específico, o teste no final é desnecessário porque o **while** já está testando se **resp == 1** a cada ciclo. A não ser que tu quisesse forçar a pessoa a escrever 1 ou 2. Porque com o código da forma em que se encontra, para qualquer valor de **resp** que não seja 1, o programa vai terminar. Experimente digitar 3 ou 4.

Answer (score -2):

Apenas coloque `while resp != 2` e assim poupa-lhe o `if else`. Quando lê o valor da consola como inteiro tente colocar assim `resp = int(input("..."))`